# Количество объектов на странице

Tags: jquery

Допустим на странице выводится 10 изображений с длиной в 50 пикселей - 1 изображение. В итоге имеем 500 пикселей.

Если отобразить страницу на ПК, то она вместит этих 10 изображений, а на смартфонах это не получится.

Вопрос: Я могу получить ширину экрана пользователя. Пусть будет: 210 пикселей. Как мне вырезать `<img>`, которые входят в последние 290 пикселей?

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, получи положение картинок относительно левой границы экрана.
Далее, если, это расстояние, или, это расстояние + ширина картинки больше размера экрана - скрыть картинку.

Функция для получения положения объекта относительно документа: `getBoundingClientRect()`.
Если тебе нужны координаты относительно текущего окна: `elementFromPoint(x, y)`.